# Trouble importing a class

Tags: python

I am having the following problem on windows 10 using visual studio 19, with python version Python 3.7.2

I am trying to use a class to get the user name and password from a text file for a logon to sql server.
The class is as follows:

```
class LogonSql:

  def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path
        print ('p = ' + self.path) # the class does not appear in this print


    def usr(self):

         lc = open(self.path,'r')


         up = lc.readlines()
         u = up[0]
         u = u.strip('\n')
         p = up[1]
         p = p.strip('\n')

         return u,p



#x = LogonSql.usr('g:\python_test\lib\jcd.txt')

#x = LogonSql('g:\python_test\lib\SqlLogon.txt')
#p = x.usr()

#print ('p = ' + p[1])
#print ('u = ' + p[0])
```

If I run the class with the above 5 uncommented it works fine.

however when i import the class I get thr following error 
in this python program I get the following error at line 11
i = LogonSql('g:\python_test\lib\SqlLogon.txt')

```
import pypyodbc
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor
import ctypes
import sysconfig
import Sql_logon

print('m = ' + str(dir('Sql_logon')))


i = LogonSql('g:\python_test\lib\SqlLogon.txt') # on this line the error happens 
                # I am slso confused to where all those other methods are coming from
x = i.usr()
u = str(x[0])
p = str(x[1])

ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0,'user  = ' + u,p,1)
con = pypyodbc.connect('DSN=mynewdsn; UID=' + u + ';PWD=' + p + ';')
cur = con.cursor()


m = ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
'__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', 
'__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', 
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'capitalize', 
'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 
'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isascii', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 
'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\python_test\testsql\testsql.py", line 11, in <module


NameError: name 'LogonSql' is not defined
```

I can not find LogonSql class in this above list?

I have set up the following in environment variables in the user area
set PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=G:\python_test\lib

In visual studio I have set search paths to PYTHONPATH

When do you need to make a compile version of the *.py code. I assume it does not need to be in the category of a dll in windows??

My naming convention probably needs some attention.

Thanks
Jack

Comment: `dir('Sql_logon')` is simply showing you the methods that string objects have - `dir(Sql_logon)` is how you'd see the contents of your imported module.  Which would presumably include `LogonSql`, so you'd access that function as `Sql_logon.LogonSql`.  Or, you could do `from Sql_logon import LogonSql`, and access it via `LogonSql` as you're currently trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would have you do is check your indenting on your `LogonSql` class.  It doesn't line up right and that can cause problems in python.

The second item is that you're not importing `LogonSql` in your main file.

You should declare the following, assuming your `LogonSql` class is stored in a file called `logonsql.py` and it's on the same directory as the file that is referencing the `LogonSql` class:

`from logonsql import LogonSql`

After which, you can call your class and proceed to use it as you wish.  See the screen capture as a reference to my structure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so  much it worked with the following.   from Sql_logon import  *   my only other question is why do python libraries, not have to use the from clause on a import. I assume all functions are included for pyhton libraries

Comment: Glad you found this answer useful.  If you can, mark it as correct (green check).

Comment: By default, not **all** functions are going to be loaded into Python, that would just be inefficient.  Rather, you can do two things: one, load all the functions/classes in a module using `import thismodule` or you can load specific functions/classes using `from thismodule load thatfunction`.  Which functions/classes you wish to load depends on what your program is trying to do.  Additionally, you can load 3rd party modules using `pip` if the base ones don't suit your need.